# NodeJS for-loop unsuccessful at trimming urls that end in with numbers

Tags: string, node.js, facebook, for-loop, replace

I'm trying to take a group of Facebook Page urls and extract only the entity title of the page. Ie for 'https://www.facebook.com/BalanceSpaBoca' I'm looking only for 'BalanceSpaBoca.' This script works great for most of the sample data I'm using (the testFBurls array), printing only the trimmed string. For others, though, it prints both the trimmed string and the original string. It seems like all of the urls that get printed twice end with a string of numbers, but I'm not sure why that should make any difference in how the program runs.

```
var testFBurls = [
    'http://www.facebook.com/pages/A-Yoga-Way/361702000576231',
    'http://www.facebook.com/aztigurbansalon',
    'https://www.facebook.com/pages/Azzurri-Salon-Spa/542579982495983',
    'https://www.facebook.com/BalanceSpaBoca',
    'https://www.facebook.com/BocaAmericanNailsandSpa',
    'http://www.facebook.com/beachyogagirl',
    'https://www.facebook.com/pages/Beauty-of-Wax/156355679240',
    'http://www.facebook.com/beehivefitness.boca',
    'https://www.facebook.com/pages/Believe-Day-Spa-Boutique/197615685896',
    'https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151725966640897&set=a.10151725965355897.1073741828.197615685896&type=1&theater',
    'http://facebook.com/pages/bigfoot-spa/1486364798260300',
    'http://www.facebook.com/bloheartsyou',
    'http://www.facebook.com/pages/The-Wellness-Center-Of-Boca-Raton/170371382995576',
    'https://www.facebook.com/TherapyBodyBalanced',
    'https://www.facebook.com/pages/BodyVital-Massage/177664492277158',
    'https://www.facebook.com/bodyworkmall',
    'https://www.facebook.com/pages/The-Bombay-Room-Yoga-Studio/148731658497764',
    ];

var possibleFBurlStarts = [
    "https://www.facebook.com/", 
    "http://www.facebook.com/", 
    "https://www.facebook.com/pages/", 
    "http://www.facebook.com/pages/",
];


for (var count=0; count<testFBurls.length; count++){
    var currentURL = testFBurls[count];
    if (currentURL.indexOf(".com/photo") > -1) {
        testFBurls.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
    }
    for (var i=0; i < possibleFBurlStarts.length; i++){
        var indexOfSubstring = currentURL.indexOf(possibleFBurlStarts[i]);
        if (indexOfSubstring > -1) {
            var res = currentURL.replace(possibleFBurlStarts[i], "");
        }
    }
    if (count == testFBurls.length-1){
        console.log(testFBurls);
    }
}
```

Here's my **console output**

```
pages/A-Yoga-Way/361702000576231
A-Yoga-Way/361702000576231
aztigurbansalon
pages/Azzurri-Salon-Spa/542579982495983
Azzurri-Salon-Spa/542579982495983
BalanceSpaBoca
BocaAmericanNailsandSpa
beachyogagirl
pages/Beauty-of-Wax/156355679240
Beauty-of-Wax/156355679240
beehivefitness.boca
pages/Believe-Day-Spa-Boutique/197615685896
Believe-Day-Spa-Boutique/197615685896
bloheartsyou
pages/The-Wellness-Center-Of-Boca-Raton/170371382995576
The-Wellness-Center-Of-Boca-Raton/170371382995576
TherapyBodyBalanced
pages/BodyVital-Massage/177664492277158
BodyVital-Massage/177664492277158
bodyworkmall
pages/The-Bombay-Room-Yoga-Studio/148731658497764
The-Bombay-Room-Yoga-Studio/148731658497764
```

Notice that the first url is listed twice (first in its original form, and secondly in its truncated form), but then the second url (the third line in the output) is listed in truncated form alone. Any ideas what is causing this disparity? Only the truncated url should be printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're modifying the array you're iterating through while you're iterating through it: `testFBurls.splice(i, 1);` which is typically a not-great thing to do. In any case, I think you should be able to accomplish your goal a lot easier with a simple regular expression:

```
for (var count=0; count<testFBurls.length; count++){
    var matches = testFBurls[count].match(/^https?\:\/\/www\.facebook\.com\/(?:pages\/)?([^\/]+)/);
    if (matches) {
        console.log('found it:', matches[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! works great and is clearly much simpler. Any advice on putting together RegEx like that, for future use?

Comment: There are a lot of [tools for learning regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info), but once you start to understand the basics it's a lot of trial and error. I use [an online tool](http://rexv.org) for evaluating a regex against a target to see what I get before I implement it in code.